# Не принимает входные параметры Spring MVC + redirect

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Когда пытаюсь получить **access_token** при обращение к API VK меня перекидывает по ссылке **http://localhost:8080/vk/login#access_token=token&expires_in=86400&user_id=id** и она правильная, но только метод **login** в контроллере **vk** отдает респонсе, что входного параметра **access_token** нету. но вот он же есть.

> HTTP Status 400 - Required String parameter 'access_token' is not present

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ApiOperation(value = "login into vk", httpMethod = "GET")
public String login (@RequestParam("access_token") String code) throws IOException {
    System.out.print(code);
    vkService.getUserCode();
    return null;
}
```

**/vk** стоит на контроллере.

Comment: Какой у Вас `redirect_uri`, тоже с этим символом `#`? если да, то удалите его.

Answer (score 0):

Ты не передаешь параметар. Замени `#` на  `?` в url-e.
спринг контроллер не читать hash param, это можно делать только на client-side, на серверной части это не работает.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508075/get-hash-parameters-in-request-url-in-spring-controller